# How to get FBA Fee and commission using Amazon MWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am going to extract order details from Amazon and store in a database. I am getting all data except FBA fee and Commission of an order.

Can anyone please guide me on this to get FBA Fee and Commision?

Answer (score 5):

The comission is part of the settlement reports you'll receive every fortnight. I'm not using FBA, but I would assume FBA fees would be included there as well where applicable. Two of those reports are automatically created whenever Amazon is preparing a payout. You can get a list of these reports (they seem to be stored forever) using the `GetReportList()` call. Their reporttypes are `_GET_FLAT_FILE_PAYMENT_SETTLEMENT_DATA_` and `_GET_V2_SETTLEMENT_REPORT_DATA_FLAT_FILE_`. The two reports cover the same settlement in different formats.

**Edit**: More details on how to do this:

1. Call `GetReportList` using the following parameters:

   'Acknowledged'          = 'false'
   'ReportTypeList.Type.1' = '_GET_FLAT_FILE_PAYMENT_SETTLEMENT_DATA_'
   'ReportTypeList.Type.2' = '_GET_V2_SETTLEMENT_REPORT_DATA_FLAT_FILE_'

   Please note: You might just want to pick just one of the two ReportTypes. 
   Also: `Acknowledged=false` is not actually needed, but I recommend acknowledging the reports you have already processed, so you'll only get a list of new reports to work on, see step 5 below.
2. You'll get a list of reports back (a "GetReportListResult"). This document gives you a list of reports. You'll need their `ReportId` for the next step.
3. Call `GetReport`using the `ReportId` from step 2
4. Parse the response. It is a CSV file ("flat file" in Amazon terminology) with all your orders within two weeks prior to the report generation.
5. Upon successfull processing, call `UpdateReportAcknowledgements` with `ReportIdList.Id.1` = ReportId from step 2 to acknowledge the report. This ensures that the next call for `GetReportList` (step 1) does not get the same data again.
6. You should get a `UpdateReportAdcknowledgementsResult` back when Amazon has set that flag.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention that I am using Amazon MWS Web Service to extract all Order Details, Can you please guide in getting FBA and Commission amounts through Amazom MWS?

Comment: @Prakki I outlined the process on how to get the settlement information in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new API _GET_FBA_ESTIMATED_FBA_FEES_TXT_DATA_

```
request = new RequestReportRequest();
request.MarketplaceIdList = new IdList();
request.Merchant = amznAccess.merchantId();
request.MarketplaceIdList.Id.Add(amznAccess.marketplaceId());
request.ReportType = "_GET_FBA_ESTIMATED_FBA_FEES_TXT_DATA_";
```

don't forget to set request start date (for eg 30 days)